# What's the meaning of "心臓って耳の中にあったんだね"?

Tags: song-lyrics

I've been wanting to translate some J-Pop songs for myself. Then I came across this song and found this phrase. I don't really understand what the phrase intend to tell at all. What I think of is this phrase tell something about someone who's really nervous, but I don't know the literal translation of it. It's more confusing because after this sentences, it's followed by "標高3000メートル？" which I assume the literal trans is "3000 meters above the sea".

I'm really glad if anyone is willing to tell me the literal translation and what does it mean. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to JLSE!  Unfortunately, this site is not set up to be a bulk translation service, and questions asking for translation are typically closed as off-topic.  To avoid getting the question closed, can you include your attempt at translation, as well as more detail as why you find the phrase confusing?

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation would be "There is a heart in my ears, isn't there?", but I think it implies that "He clearly can hear his heart beating", because he likes her. When people like someone, their heart are beating, aren't they?

The sentence after 標高3000メートル is 酸素が足りない. In 3000 meters above the sea, oxygen is a little. So it implies that "He  has difficulty in his breathing". When people like someone, it sometimes happens, isn't it?

So the sentences are figurative expression and imply that "His heart are beating and he has difficulty in his breathing because he likes her."

This is the song. https://mojim.com/twy118703x9x4.htm